# chainging the registration point of a mc with as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, registration, point, movieclip

i have a grid gallery and i want to rotate it according to the mouse position.
i managed to rotate it very well but the only problem is that i can't change the registration point of my mc container because i created my mc using as3.
by the way i managed to solve the problem somewhere else by creating the mc manually and change it's color to my stage color but things go bad when i want to change the color of stage!!!
here is the code of my grid gallery:

```
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import fl.controls.ProgressBar;
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;
import flash.geom.Matrix;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;

// details of XML
var columns:Number;
var my_x:Number;
var my_y:Number;
var my_thumb_width:Number;
var my_thumb_height:Number;
var my_images:XMLList;
var my_total:Number;

var container_mc:MovieClip;

/*
var dpObj = container_mc.getChildAt(0); //the dipslay object or graphic you movie clip               contains
var mat:Matrix = dpObj.transform.matrix;
var bounds:Rectangle = container_mc.getBounds(dpObj); // get the bounds relative to the     movie clip
mat.tx = -bounds.left; //left and top will be the registration point of the clip
mat.ty = -bounds.top;
*/
var full_mc:MovieClip;

var preloaders_mc:MovieClip;

var x_counter:Number = 0;
var y_counter:Number = 0;

var my_tweens:Array = [];
var container_mc_tween:Tween;
var full_tween:Tween;

var myXMLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myXMLLoader.load(new URLRequest("gallery.xml"));
myXMLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

function processXML (e:Event):void{
var myXML:XML = new XML(e.target.data);

columns = myXML.@COLUMNS;
my_x = (stage.stageWidth - (columns*110)+10)/2;
my_y = (stage.stageHeight - (columns*110)+10)/2;
my_thumb_width = myXML.@WIDTH;
my_thumb_height = myXML.@HEIGHT;
my_images = myXML.IMAGE;
my_total = my_images.length();

createContainer();
callThumbs();
myXMLLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);
myXMLLoader = null;
}
function createContainer():void{
container_mc = new MovieClip();  // ino dorostesh kon - bayad pivotesh vasat bashe
container_mc.x = my_x;
container_mc.y = my_y;
addChild(container_mc);
container_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, callFull);
container_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onOver);
container_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onOut);
container_mc.buttonMode = true;

preloaders_mc = new MovieClip();
preloaders_mc.x = container_mc.x;
preloaders_mc.y = container_mc.y;
addChild(preloaders_mc);
}
function callThumbs():void{
for (var i:Number = 0; i < my_total; i++){
    var thumb_url = my_images[i].@THUMB;;
    var thumb_loader = new Loader();
    thumb_loader.load(new URLRequest(thumb_url));
    thumb_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, thumbLoaded);

    thumb_loader.name = i;

    thumb_loader.x = (my_thumb_width+10)*x_counter;
    thumb_loader.y = (my_thumb_height+10)*y_counter;
    if (x_counter+1 < columns){
        x_counter++;
    } else {
        x_counter = 0;
        y_counter++;
    }
    var preloader_pb:ProgressBar = new ProgressBar();
    preloader_pb.source = thumb_loader.contentLoaderInfo;
    preloader_pb.x = thumb_loader.x;
    preloader_pb.y = thumb_loader.y+50;
    preloader_pb.width = my_thumb_width;
    preloaders_mc.addChild(preloader_pb);

    preloader_pb.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, donePb);
}
}
function thumbLoaded(e:Event):void{
var my_thumb:Loader = Loader(e.target.loader);
container_mc.addChild(my_thumb);
my_tweens[Number(my_thumb.name)]=new Tween(my_thumb, "alpha", Strong.easeIn, 0,1,0.5, true);
my_thumb.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, thumbLoaded);
}
function callFull(e:MouseEvent):void{
var full_loader:Loader = new Loader();
var full_url = my_images[e.target.name].@FULL;
full_loader.load(new URLRequest(full_url));
full_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, fullLoaded);

var full_pb:ProgressBar = new ProgressBar();
full_pb.source = full_loader.contentLoaderInfo;
full_pb.x = (stage.stageWidth - full_pb.width)/2;
full_pb.y = (stage.stageHeight - full_pb.height)/2;
preloaders_mc.addChild(full_pb);

full_pb.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, donePb)

container_mc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, callFull);
container_mc.buttonMode = false;
container_mc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onOver);
container_mc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onOut);
container_mc_tween = new Tween(container_mc, "alpha", Strong.easeIn, 1,0.5,0.5, true);
}
function fullLoaded(e:Event):void{
full_mc = new MovieClip;
full_mc.buttonMode = true;
addChild (full_mc);
var my_loader:Loader = Loader(e.target.loader);
full_mc.addChild(my_loader);
full_tween = new Tween(my_loader, "alpha", Strong.easeIn, 0,1,0.5, true);
my_loader.x = (stage.stageWidth - my_loader.width)/2;
my_loader.y = (stage.stageHeight - my_loader.height)/2;
my_loader.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removeFull);
my_loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.INIT, fullLoaded);
}
function removeFull(e:Event):void{
var my_loader:Loader = Loader(e.currentTarget);
full_tween = new Tween(my_loader, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1,0,0.5, true);
full_tween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, tweenFinished);

container_mc_tween = new Tween(container_mc, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0.5,1,0.5, true);
}
function donePb (e:Event):void{
var my_pb:ProgressBar = ProgressBar(e.target);
preloaders_mc.removeChild(my_pb);
my_pb.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, donePb);
}
function tweenFinished (e:TweenEvent):void{
var my_loader:Loader = Loader (e.target.obj);
my_loader.unload();
full_mc.removeChild(my_loader);
removeChild(full_mc);
full_mc = null;
container_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, callFull);
container_mc.buttonMode = true;
container_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onOver);
container_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onOut);

var my_tween:Tween = Tween(e.target);
my_tween.removeEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, tweenFinished);
}
function onOver (e:MouseEvent):void{
var my_thumb:Loader = Loader(e.target);
my_thumb.alpha = 0.5;
}
function onOut (e:MouseEvent):void{
var my_thumb:Loader = Loader(e.target);
my_thumb.alpha = 1;
}
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, moveMyMc);
function moveMyMc(e:MouseEvent):void{
    if(mouseX > 0){
        container_mc.rotationY = (20) -1 *(mouseX * (40 / stage.width));
    }
    if(mouseY > 0){
        container_mc.rotationX = (-20) + (mouseY * (40 / stage.height));
    }
}
```

as you can see i tried some other ways to change the code here but they did't work.
i've also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375231/center-movieclip-on-point) one and [this one](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2010/08/04/changing-a-movieclip-registration-point-on-the-fly-with-as3/)
but i couldn't solve the problem
and thanks to google :D i found [this class](http://frostmage.persiangig.com/2d_stuff/PointMovieClip.as) too but i don't now how should i use it.

Answer (score 0):

to use that class you found, just set your container_mc class to PointMovieClip instead of MovieClip. Then you can call **container_mc.registrationX** = wanted center and **container_mc.registrationY** = wanted center to set your container registration point. After that set rotation to it.

Comment: thanks man but where should i copy the file? - do i need to importe the class or not!?

Comment: you should copy that file to your source path -folder. The package name is com.zehfernando.display so you should put it in folder **com/zehfernando/display** in your source path with filename **PointMovieClip.as**. Check/modify your source path in flash actionscipt settings.